# Ember data 2.0 access relationship from template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm having trouble accessing a relationship inside the ember templates

- Ember & Ember Data 2.0.0
- ActiveModelAdaptar - via plugin

Ember Store in console, shows that the current item has a relationship that is already computed, but I can't access it from template

[image]

Grouped Item Model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  group:          DS.belongsTo('group', { async :  false }),
  groupable_id:   DS.attr('number'),
  groupable_type: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Group Model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    code:          DS.attr('string'),
    name:          DS.attr('string'),
    description:   DS.attr('string'),
    adyuz_site_id: DS.attr('number'),
    extra:         DS.attr(),
    display_as:    DS.attr(),
    items:         DS.hasMany('groupedItem', { async: false, inverse: 'group' }),
});
```

JSON

[image]

Index Route model

```
  model: function(){
    var self = this;

    return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all([
      this.store.query('groupedItem', { group_code: 'HOME', position : 1 }),
      this.store.query('groupedItem', { group_code: 'HOME', position : 2 }),
    ]);
  },
```

Index template

```
{#each model as |section|}}
  {{#each section.content as |item|}}
    {{item}} | {{item.group.id}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Any suggestions, migration deprecations?

Comment: Can you post template code where you have problems with accessing relationship? Can you setup demo of this issue?

Comment: let me replicate it on a jsbin

Comment: seems the issue is to stop sending relational ids as model_id... json is expecting to have just belongs to modelname: id.... needs to use a custom serializer with a normalize response

Comment: I am running into the same problem, did you manage to solve it abFx?